# React Native - Fetch POST request is sending as GET request

Tags: react-native

I'm having issues when using FETCH.

I am trying to make a POST request using FETCH in react-native.

```
    fetch("http://www.example.co.uk/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: 'test',
            password: 'test123',
        })
    })

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(
                "POST Response",
                "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
            )
        })
        .done();
}
```

When I inspect this call using Charles it is recorded as a GET request and the username and password that should be in the body are not there.

[image]

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080130/react-fetch-can-get-but-never-posts?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue when the POST request was to an HTTPS (rather than HTTP) server. For some reason, it would somewhere along the way be converted into a GET request.

It turns out what I was doing incorrectly was sending the request to `http://myserver.com:80` rather than to `https://myserver.com:443`. Once I switched it over to the proper prefix and ports, the request would properly send as a POST.

Comment: Had same thing happen.

Comment: When a POST is redirected (in my case from http to https) it gets transformed into a GET (Where is the logic in that??), https requests worked perfectly in my case, without the ports appended to the domain!

Comment: It seems that this is a badly implemented feature accros almost any browser: https://serverfault.com/questions/434205/nginx-https-rewrite-turns-post-to-get

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
let data = {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  mode: 'same-origin',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    appoid: appo_id
  }),
  headers: {
    'Accept':       'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRFToken':  cookie.load('csrftoken')
  }
}
return fetch('/appointments/get_appos', data)
        .then(response => response.json())  // promise
        .then(json => dispatch(receiveAppos(json)))
}
```

Comment: What is cookie here?

Answer (score 6):

Use FormData. Problem is with JSON.stringify. You can directly import, its not third party

```
import FormData from 'FormData';
...
var data = new FormData();
data.append("username", "ABCD");
data.append("password", "1234");
fetch('YOUR_URL', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
},
body:data,
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log('response object:',responseJson)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same kind of issue. You have to assign the object, not sure why.

let options = {};

options.body = formdata;

options.header = header;

options.method = 'post';

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. That would result in the exact same object..

Comment: maybe it conflicted with this new features of ES6? http://www.2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html

Comment: I've seen this issue also in an app that defined directly in the fetch function as argument and not in another app where I defined the object like --- let options = Object.assign(
            {method: verb},
            requestParams ? {body: JSON.stringify(requestParams)} : null,
            {headers: headers}
        ); --- So it seems that this is the correct anwser!

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch it should be possible to define the object as argument... or is this maybe a iOS specific issue???

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the redirect was caused by wrongly formed url for the POST request:
`http://localhost:90/Worx/drupal/d8/www//jsonapi`
double slash before jsonapi

Because of the wrong url, the browser was redirecting the request and changing the method from POST to GET.

I was able to debug it after reading this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/434205/nginx-https-rewrite-turns-post-to-get

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna do POST request using fetch, You can do like that

```
        fetch('url?email=a@gmail.com&password=a@gmail.com', {
             method: 'POST'
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
             console.log(responseJson);
             // this.setState({
             //    data: responseJson
             // })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
             console.error(error);
          });
```

Comment: How Can I display Json data in listview using post method?

Comment: convert json to array and loop it.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother @Ryosuke

Comment: Hey brother can you please help..  please have a look on below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764351/how-to-display-json-data-on-listview-react-native-by-post-request-api

Comment: Hi could you help me for this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801602/how-to-generate-dynaimc-ui-on-json-response-react-native  .. please , because I am stuck and don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Redirection of url converts the POST request into GET requests.(Don't know why)
So make sure of adding trailing arrows if any.
like :"http://www.example.co.uk/login/"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case I had an extra `/` at the end of my route. I removed it and problem solved.

`http://google.com/someData/` to `http://google.com/someData`

Answer (score 0):

**I have made some changes and tested it, works fine for me, check below all the changes:**

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true};
    this.getRemoteData();
 }

getRemoteData = () => {

fetch('http://www.example.co.uk/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: 'test',
                password: 'test123',
            })
        })

            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                console.log("RESULTS HERE:", responseData)

            this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        }, function(){

        });
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      }) 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your OPTIONS response. It probably has a `302 redirect` or similar.

In our case, Django didn't like it if the URL didn't end in a `/`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rishijay's answer, my issue was with JSON.stringify not properly converting the body of POST request.

The way I solved this was using build from the search-params node module to make it work.
My fetch contents had body like this `body: build({...})`

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me!**

```
 const params = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: '1',
        name: 'user',
        age: '26',
      
      }),
    };
    fetch('https://yourapi/', params)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```