# How to get JSON dynamic value in Picker React-native

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-native

Here am trying to get value in Picker , I am getting value in JSON format and trying to show that value in Picker like DropDown .
Please help. Below code am trying like hit and trial but not working .
Below is my code and JSON value also . 
Do I need to install and dependencies ?

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Platform, Picker, ActivityIndicator, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';

    export default class AddInventory extends Component {

     componentDidMount() {

          return  fetch('http://1/Dsenze/userapi/inventory/viewinventorytype', {  
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              "username" :"admin",
              "password" :"admin"
            })
          }).then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            var count = Object.keys(responseJson.message.Obj).length;
            let PickerValueHolder = [];
            for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
              console.log(responseJson.message.Obj[i].name) // I need to add 
              PickerValueHolder.push({ value: responseJson.message.Obj[i].name }); // Create your array of data
            }
            this.setState({ PickerValueHolder }); // Set the new state
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
        }

        GetPickerSelectedItemValue=()=>{

          Alert.alert(this.state.PickerValueHolder);
        }

     render() {

       return (

        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

              <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolder}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerValueHolder: itemValue})} >
                { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
                <Picker.Item label={item.name} value={item.name} key={key} />)
                )}

              </Picker>

              <Button title="Click Here To Get Picker Selected Item Value" onPress={ this.GetPickerSelectedItemValue } />

        </View>

       );
     }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    MainContainer :{

    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex:1,
    margin: 10
    }

    });
```

// below is JSON response

```
{
  "inventoryTypeData": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "scanning equipment"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ecg machine"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "ct-scan machine"
  }, {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "x-ray machine"
  }],
  "success": "true"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few issues in your code

1. You don't need a return statement in your `componentDidMount`
2. You're not accessing the values correctly in your `responseJson`, there is no key called messages
3. You are using a `for-loop` when you could just use the array from the `responseJson`.
4. In your picker you are overwriting the `PickerValueHolder` which holds all the values each time you move the picker.

I have made some changes to your code, and this is a working example, which you can see here at this snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/picker-example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Alert, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  // add a selectValue to your state to stop the overwriting
  state = {
    PickerValueHolder: [],
    selectedValue: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // remove the return 
   fetch('http://1/Dsenze/userapi/inventory/viewinventorytype', {  
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "username" :"admin",
          "password" :"admin"
        })
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // use the inventoryTypeData as it is already an array
        let PickerValueHolder = responseJson.inventoryTypeData;
        this.setState({ PickerValueHolder }); // Set the new state
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }

  GetPickerSelectedItemValue=()=>{
    Alert.alert(this.state.PickerValueHolder);
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {<Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({selectedValue: itemValue})} >
                { this.state.PickerValueHolder.map((item, key)=>
                  <Picker.Item label={item.name} value={item.name} key={key} />
                )}
              </Picker>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew , let me trey , but here you have used expo , ?

Comment: Expo is react-native, it is a great tool for testing and prototyping on. If it works in Expo, it will work in a full react-native app.

Comment: Thanks Andrew , thanks for teaching me all this thing .. I'll learn all this thing very soon .. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Andrew , could you please help me for one more question please , after that I won't disturb you .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801602/how-to-generate-dynaimc-ui-on-json-response-react-native       Please

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Alert, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'react-native';

export default class AddInventory extends React.Component {

  // add a selectValue to your state to stop the overwriting
  state = {
    PickerValueHolder: [],
    selectedValue: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // remove the return 
   fetch('http:///Dsenze/userapi/inventory/viewinventorytype', {  
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "username" :"admin",
          "password" :"admin"
        })
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // use the inventoryTypeData as it is already an array
        let PickerValueHolder = responseJson.inventoryTypeData;
        this.setState({ PickerValueHolder }); // Set the new state
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }

  GetPickerSelectedItemValue=()=>{
    Alert.alert(this.state.PickerValueHolder);
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {<Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({selectedValue: itemValue})} >
                { this.state.PickerValueHolder.map((item, key)=>
                  <Picker.Item label={item.name} value={item.name} key={key} />
                )}
              </Picker>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```