# How to Generate dynaimc UI on JSON response react-native

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

// Here I am trying to generate Dynamic UI . Through API I am getting some response in JSON format , I have to draw that on UI . Like am not defining any "TextInput" it should generate dynamically.Below is some sample JSON response .That may change on different request . 
Please help , I am stuck below is just one code, I don't know how to do that .

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Alert, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

var myloop = [];
export default class UiDynamic extends React.Component {

  // add a selectValue to your state to stop the overwriting
  state = {
    PickerValueHolder: [],
    selectedValue: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // remove the return 
   fetch('http://userapi/inventory/viewinventorytype', {  
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "username" :"admin",
          "password" :"admin"
        })
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // use the inventoryTypeData as it is already an array
        let PickerValueHolder = responseJson.inventoryTypeData;
        for (let i = 0; i < PickerValueHolder.length; i++) {
            datavalue=() => {
                <Text>Hello ABhi</Text>
                console.log("Hello ABhi");   
            }
        }

        this.setState({ PickerValueHolder }); // Set the new state
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }

  GetPickerSelectedItemValue=()=>{
    Alert.alert(this.state.PickerValueHolder);
  }

  render() {


    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        datavalue=() => {
            <Text>Hello ABhi</Text>
            console.log("Hello ABhi");   
        }
      myloop.push(
        <View key={<TextInput></TextInput>}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 5 }} >{<Text>Hello</Text>}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.datavalue.bind(this)}
      {myloop}

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

// Below is Sample JSON Response ..
Suppose here am getting four attributes and their datatype , So on UI 4 "TextInput" should generate .

```
{
  "inventoryTypeData": [{
    "data type": int,
    "Field 1": ""
  }, {
    "data type": string,
    "Field2": ""
  }, {
    "data type": int,
    "Field 3": ""
  }, {
    "datatype": int,
    "Field4": ""
  }],
  "success": "true"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`import { TextInput } from 'react-native';`

Once you have mapped your response to state
`this.setState({ PickerValueHolder });`

You can then loop through it in your render method with the map function

````
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.PickerValueHolder.map(data=>(
        <View>
          <TextInput
            placeholder={data.placeholder}
            keyboardType={data.datatype==="int" ? 'numeric': 'default'}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({...this.state.value [data.name]: text })}
            value={this.state.value[data.name]}
          />
          <Button
            onPress={this.handleButtonPress(data.name).bind(this)}
          />
        <View/>
      />
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}```

So here you are checking if the datatype is an int and then setting the keyboard type to numeric

This is also setting all the changes to a value object in state.

The Button calls a function with the name of of the value related to the text input
````

Comment: Thanks .. one thing how I'll put placeholder and is there is button on response I have to generate one button also

Comment: So you want to map it to a TextInput with the data as placeholder and a button to submit any changes?

Comment: Basically in retrun function I am not writing any Textinput or button or text ,  once I open the app I'll get response from server sometime 4 response then I have to draw 4 fields  if 10 then 10 fields include placeholder ,data type and button ,picker textinput, depends on JSON response

Comment: I think the changes match your requirements?

Comment: Thanks for valuable time  ,I'll try that also ,but 

Is that possible that after getting response from API in JSON format , we can draw dynamic UI , like if getting 5 attributes in JSON then 5 Textinput or if getting 10 then 10 textinput . I need some help and direction

Comment: is there is not Textinput response then no Textinput field

Comment: We are looping over the PickerValueHolder. So for every attribute you get from the JSON it should make a TextInput and a button.

Comment: could you please make one example for me , I m not able to implement ..

Comment: Can u please help for this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845003/how-to-save-share-or-download-qrcode-in-png-format-in-react-native