# Populating picker in react native through fetch from the server

Tags: json, react-native, picker

I am trying to get picker values from the server to my react-native project. this is my JSON data. How do I fetch it for the picker component? I tried all d methods from web results. but I get only a blank screen. Kindly please help

```
{
"MFBasic": {
    "SkinTones": "DARK,FAIR,VFAIR",
    "Build": "SLIM,ATHLETIC,PLUMPY",
    "Gender": "F,M,T",
    "Genre": "ACTION,COMEDY,DRAMA",
    "Languages": "ENG,HINDI,TAM",
    "MediaModes": "ADS,MOVIES,SHORTFILMS",
    "Tags": "BIKES,HOME,JEWELLARY"
},
"Result": "Successfully Loaded MF Basic Details",
"Code": 100
```

}

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {


    state = {

        PickerValueHolder:[],
        Gender:'',
        }
   componentDidMount() {
      fetch('https://movieworld.sramaswamy.com/GetMFBasicDetails.php', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

           let PickerValueHolder = responseJson.MFBasic;
           this.setState({ PickerValueHolder }); // Set the new state

           }).catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
          });
         }



     render() {
        return (
          <View style = {styles.MainContainer}>
           {<Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.Gender}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
            this.setState({Gender:itemValue})} >
            { this.state.PickerValueHolder.map((item, key)=>
            <Picker.Item label={item.Gender} value={item.Gender} key={key}/>
            )}
         </Picker>}
        </View>
       );
      }
     }
```

above code is my app.js file. but it returns nothing to the picker.help me please. Thank u.

Comment: Please provide code to your fetch-request and component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON dynamic value in Picker React-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784307/how-to-get-json-dynamic-value-in-picker-react-native)

Comment: @Mukeyii. thank u so much for the reply. i have edited and added the code.kindly help.

Comment: @Andrew Thank u for the reply. I have used code from that link only. but no values returned to picker. picker is blank

Comment: @priyaarokiadass see my answer below for working a picker example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the json from your API call

```
{
    "MFBasic": {
        "SkinTones": "DARK,FAIR,VFAIR",
        "Build": "SLIM,ATHLETIC,PLUMPY",
        "Gender": "F,M,T",
        "Genre": "ACTION,COMEDY,DRAMA",
        "Languages": "ENG,HINDI,TAM",
        "MediaModes": "ADS,MOVIES,SHORTFILMS",
        "Tags": "BIKES,HOME,JEWELLARY"
    },
    "Result": "Successfully Loaded MF Basic Details",
    "Code": 100
}
```

The issue that is that you are trying to set a string where it needs an array. You can do it by doing something like this:

```
let genderString = responseJson.MFBasic.Gender;
let genderArray = genderString.split(',');
this.setState({ PickerValueHolder: genderArray });
```

```js
let responseJson = {
    "MFBasic": {
        "SkinTones": "DARK,FAIR,VFAIR",
        "Build": "SLIM,ATHLETIC,PLUMPY",
        "Gender": "F,M,T",
        "Genre": "ACTION,COMEDY,DRAMA",
        "Languages": "ENG,HINDI,TAM",
        "MediaModes": "ADS,MOVIES,SHORTFILMS",
        "Tags": "BIKES,HOME,JEWELLARY"
    },
    "Result": "Successfully Loaded MF Basic Details",
    "Code": 100
}

let genderString = responseJson.MFBasic.Gender;
let genderArray = genderString.split(',');
console.log(genderArray)
```

Because the items in your array are just strings you cannot access them by using `item.Gender` that won't work. You need to just access them using `item`.

I have created an example based on your code and implemented the change from above and fixed the `Picker.Item` component so it should render now.  You can see the working code at the following snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/picker-with-array-of-strings

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {

      PickerValueHolder: [],
      Gender: ''
    }
    componentDidMount () {
      fetch('https://movieworld.sramaswamy.com/GetMFBasicDetails.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          let genderString = responseJson.MFBasic.Gender;
          let genderArray = genderString.split(',');
          this.setState({ PickerValueHolder: genderArray });
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }

    render () {
      console.log(this.state.PickerValueHolder)
      return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
          {<Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.Gender}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              this.setState({ Gender: itemValue })} >
            { this.state.PickerValueHolder.map((item, key) =>
              <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={key}/>
            )}
          </Picker>}
        </View>
      );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I can understand it now well. Thanks a lot

Comment: am getting the output on snack but not in my emulator.am not using expo here.. am using react-native

Comment: The javascript code for `Expo` will work in `react-native`.

Comment: sorry for disturbing u. could u please help me with this?.Thank u so much

Comment: the picker is empty in the emulator

Comment: If your code is the same as mine then it will work. You need to check each line and make sure that it matches. Just look at the code in the `componentDidMount` and `render` functions. That is what is important to you

Comment: yes thank u so so much. i jus restarted my emulator n run the program. now its working.. Thank u for ur help. it means a lot to me.

Comment: Is the logic same for multiselect picker too?

Comment: I would imagine so, however if you have a new question your should ask a [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) question

Comment: Thank you so much. I posted a new question:).Please help me