# POST Fetch request returns: grant_type was not specified

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, fetch

I had working code for fetching a access token with oauth, then I did a expo eject and now when I  try to POST my auth code to get the access_token i receive response.

```
.then((auth_code) => {
        let my_headers = new Headers()
        my_headers.append('Authorization', `Basic ${base64_auth}`)
        my_headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        my_headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        my_headers.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code')

        let urlencoded = new URLSearchParams()

        urlencoded.append('code', auth_code)
        urlencoded.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code')              // <-- GRANT_TYPE HERE

        let request_options = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: my_headers,
          body: urlencoded,
          mode: 'cors'
        }
        console.log(request_options) // <--- OUTPUT BELOW

        let url_with_params = `https://${url}/oauth/token/`
        fetch(url_with_params, request_options)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => console.log(json))                               // <--- OUTPUT BELOW
          .then((json) => helpers.set_session_object('oauth_object', json))
          .finally(() => set_loading(false))
          .catch((error) => console.log('error', error))
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

console.log(request_options) outputs the following:

```
{method: "POST", headers: Headers, body: URLSearchParams, mode: "cors"}
body: URLSearchParams {_searchParams: Array(1)}
headers: Headers
  map:
    access-control-allow-origin: "*"
    authorization: "Basic YXdheTprTkwpUmtWc2lWM2ppaCk3WDlmZXp3aSk="
    content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    grant_type: "authorization_code"
method: "POST"
mode: "cors"
```

and the json response outputs:

```
{"error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "The grant type was not specified in the request"}
```

Any idea why this is happening? I obviously have the grant_type declared right?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this I can see a couple of things that may not be quite right:

- Remove the **trailing backslash** at the end of the OAuth token URL
- Include a **redirect_uri** field, which is required in Authorization Code Grant messages

I suspect the first issue above is causing a redirect so that the POST to **https://url/oauth/token/** becomes a GET to **https://url/oauth/token**.

Some similar issues are described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140358/react-native-fetch-post-request-is-sending-as-get-request), and above all else I would aim to ensure that you can use an HTTP Proxy tool to view messages, which will make you much more productive at diagnosing this type of issue in future.

**PROXY MOBILE SETUP**

If it helps, my blog has some posts on proxy setup details:

- [Android HTTP Proxy Setup](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/21/android-https-debugging/)
- [iOS HTTP Proxy Setup](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/ios-https-debugging/)