# React app fetch POST request Cannot GET / when using POST commands

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, post, get

I am using react app - when running node index.js I get "Cannot GET /" error directly on my browser(I want to run it directly), despite requesting POST command, GET request worked ok earlier.

I am following this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/bB7xkRsEq-g?t=1269

which seemed to do this with no issues

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch('http://localhost:3001/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setResponse(data.message))
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <textarea
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>{response}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({
        message: "Hello World"
    });
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on localhost: ${port}`);
});
```

Here is a screen shot of dev tools showing it is trying to do a GET request.
Upon reviewing my server logs, I've noticed that no POST requests are being sent. It appears that the "fetch" function is disregarding the specified "method" parameter. Instead, it consistently performs "GET" requests, regardless of my attempt to instruct it to execute a "POST" request.

[image: dev tools]

Also couldn't find something useful in this post:
[React Native - Fetch POST request is sending as GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140358/react-native-fetch-post-request-is-sending-as-get-request/41492998#41492998)

Comment: You're only running your Express app, which has nothing to do with your React app.

Comment: You need to run your react app along side your express server, by accessing localhost:3001 in the browser you are performing a GET request which has no end point set in the server. in the video you mentioned he defined a GET endpoint that is why he is getting "hello world" as a response in the browser. in 19:26 he started the react app in localhost:3000, it's what i think you forgot to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is from your Express.js app.

You're only allowing `POST` on the `/` endpoint, which is why you're getting the "Cannot GET /" error when trying to access `/`.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({
        message: "Hello World"
    });
});
```

#### Edit

It looks like you've mistakenly opened your backend in the browser instead of your React app.

Comment: How can I access the react app using the browser?
Now I write this "http://localhost:3001/" and get the mentioned error
Thanks

Comment: That's because your Express.js is using port 3001. Try opening localhost:3000 instead

Comment: make sure you run it first "npm start" in the app directory not the server, and write  "localhost:3000" instead of  "localhost:3001" in the browser

Comment: Ok, problem solved :) Correct me if im wrong:
What I missed is that React is the frontend and express is the backend, they both need to run simultaneously, and to do so I needed to open 2 terminals and run 'npm start' for the react app and 'node index.js' for the express backend app. Now they both run together on port 3000(the frontend). Thanks